# How do I say "if x == A or B or C" as succinctly as possible?

Tags: ruby

I'm pretty sure ruby has an idiom for that.

I just have too many places in my code where I say

```
if (x == A) || (x == B) || (x ==C)
  do_something
else
  do_something_else
end
```

I know I also could do

```
case x
when A, B, C
   do_something
else
   do_something_else
end
```

but I prefer using `if else` if there's a nice idiom to make it more succinct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can an "if (a == b || c == b)" statement be done shorter in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584852/can-an-if-a-b-c-b-statement-be-done-shorter-in-ruby)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tidy up your `case` statement a bit more like this

```
case x
when A, B, C then do_something
else do_something_else
end
```

or if it is a repeating pattern, roll it into a method on `Object`

```
class Object
  def is_one_of?(*inputs)
    inputs.include?(self)
  end
end
```

then use it as

```
if x.is_one_of?(A, B, C)
  do_something
else
  do_something_else
end
```

Comment: that's cool, thank you. dumb additional question, I know, but where would I put that Object method in a rails 3 app? That's a perfect solution for something my app does a lot of which is decide to enable/disable certain features depending upon the particular 'type' of user account.

Comment: I think the best place would be a separate file under the `lib` directory.

Comment: I also use this abstraction (Object#in?), it appeared in some old SO question.

Answer (score 39):

One way would be `[A, B, C].include?(x)`

Answer (score 0):

Other ways:

```
A,B,C = 1,2,3
arr = [A, B, C]
x = 2
y = 4
```

*Use [Array#&](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-26)*

```
[x] & arr == [x]
  #=> true
[y] & arr == [y]
  #=> false
```

*Use [Array#-](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-2D)*

```
([x] - arr).empty?
  #=> true
([y] - arr).empty?
  #=> false
```

*Use [Array#|](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-7C)*

```
arr | [x] == arr
  #=> true
arr | [y] == arr
  #=> false
```

*Use [Array#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-index)*

```
arr.index(x)
  #=> 1 (truthy)
arr.index(y)
  #=> nil (falsy)

!!arr.index(x)
  #=> true
!!arr.index(y)
  #=> false
```

*Use @edgerunner's solution, generalized*

```
def present?(arr, o)
  case o
  when *arr
     puts "#{o} matched"
  else
     puts "#{o} not matched"
  end
end

present?(arr, x)
  # 2 matched
present?(arr, y)
  # 4 not matched
```