# Can an "if (a == b || c == b)" statement be done shorter in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a piece of code in Ruby which goes as follows:

```
def check
  if a == b || c == b
  # execute some code
  # b = the same variable
  end
end
```

can this be written like

```
def check
  if a || c == b
  # this doesn't do the trick
  end
  if (a || c) == b
  # this also doesn't do the magic as I thought it would
  end
end
```

Or in a manner where I don't need to type `b` twice. This is out of laziness and I would like to know.

Comment: what was wrong with `(a||c) == b`?  It's backwards imo, as I'd suggest trying `b == (a||c)' (which follows better boolean algebra conventions).

Comment: @acolyte What of the case when `a=1` `c=0` `b=0`?

Comment: @RyanAmos then b == c, therefore the conditional evaluates to true.  unless ruby has some alternate meaning for `||`.  I was assuming that stood for logical OR.

Comment: @acolyte `(a || c)` ==> 1 `1 == 0` ==> 0 On the other hand `0 || 1` ==> 1. This is assuming that C-like boolean operators work the same as Ruby boolean operators. (not a Ruby programmer)

Comment: @RyanAmos hmmm, interesting.  perhaps i was mistaken.  it's almost like we need some sort of non-logical OR.  something to basically say this or that, and NOT evaluating for truth.  Selection OR perhaps?

Comment: @acolyte `(a||c)` is `b` if `a` is logical false (that is, `false` or `nil`) and `a` otherwise.

Comment: `a, b, c = 1, 2, 2` would lead to `2 == (1||2)` which leads to `2 == 1` which is false since all ints are truthy values in Ruby and `(a||b)` will pick a if a is truthy or otherwise it will pick b no matter what.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
if [a, c].include? b
  # code
end
```

This is, however, significantly slower than the code you want to avoid -- at least as long as `a`, `b` and `c` are basic data. My measurements showed a factor of 3. This is probably due to the additional `Array` object creation. So you might have to weigh DRY against performance here. Normally it should not matter, though, because both variants do not take long.

Comment: Nice, but it's actually 1 character longer, I guess it depends on the variable names. Does it have an impact on performance ?

Comment: @zakinster: :-) Character count was not the objective of the question. The point is more to avoid repetition. Instead of `b` there could be something more complex. Or, when exchanging `b` by another variable you don't have to change it in two places (less errors).

Comment: The number of characters, or of white spaces, only have a marginal effect during the initial interpreter pass through the code. After that character count is a non-issue. Changing algorithms and methods used has a greater effect on execution speed.

Answer (score 6):

While not an exact equivalent of `a == b || a == c`, `case` statement offers syntax for this:

```
case a
when b, c then puts "It's b or c."
else puts "It's something else."
end
```

Feel free to opent the nearest Ruby textbook and read about how `case` statement works. Spoiler: It works by calling `#===` method on the compared objects:

```
a = 42
b, c = Object.new, Object.new
def b.=== other; puts "b#=== called" end
def c.=== other; puts "c#=== called" end
```

Now run

```
case a
when b, c then true
else false end
```

This gives you a lot of flexibility. It requires work in the back office, but after you do it, looks like magic in the front office.

Comment: this seems the most rubyonic way to me. clean and readable! (also, +1 for the 42)

Comment: Note this can be generalized and implemented dynmically: `arr = [b,c]; case a; when *arr then...`.

Answer (score 3):

You should really know why this doesn't work:

```
(a || c) == b
```

This seems like a translation of the sentence "a or c is equal b", which makes sense in English.

In almost all programming languages, `(a || c)` is an expression, whose evaluated result will be compared to `b`. The translation to English is *"The result of the operation "a or c" is equal to b"*.

Answer (score 0):

@undur_gongor's answer is perfectly correct. Just to add though, if you're working with arrays, for example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
c = [4,5,6]

b = [5,6]

if [a, c].include? b
  # won't work if your desired result is true
end
```

You'd have to do something like:

```
if [a,c].any?{ |i| (i&b).length == b.length }
  # assuming that you're always working with arrays
end

# otherwise ..
if [a,c].any?{ |i| ([i].flatten&[b].flatten).length == [b].flatten.length }
  # this'll handle objects other than arrays too.
end
```

Answer (score -1):

What about this?
if [a,c].index(b) != nil;puts "b = a or b = c";end

Answer (score -1):

Acolyte pointed out you can use `b == (a||c)`, you just had it backwards, but that only works for the left value, since (a||c) is always a, assuming a isn't falsey.

Another option is to use a ternary operator.

```
a==b ? true : b==c
```

I'm not sure of the speed difference cited wrt the array approach, but I would think this could be faster since it's doing either one or two comparisons and doesn't need to deal with arrays. Also, I assume it's the exact same as (a==b || b==c), but it's a stylistic alternative.